# Parse Javascript- Upload image with some other parameters

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to Upload image with some other parameters on parse, but i didn't find any code to store image with other parameters.

I want to use JavaScript or REST API. Please suggest me right code or some  right direction.

Currently i am using REST API to upload the parameters not file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To upload string data to server i used REST API  ----   var userData ={//String parameters};
var data = JSON.stringify(userData);
var header1 = {"X-Parse-Application-Id":"appId", "X-Parse-REST-API-Key":"restapiId"};
$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/classname",headers: header1,dataType: "json",contentType: "application/json",data: data,success: function(data){alert("Record submitted: ");},error: function(e) {console.log(e);}});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can do as follows - currently it is with name parameter but you can pass multiple parameters with it. Hope this helps you -

```
var file;

// Set an event listener on the Choose File field.
$('#idoffiletag').bind("change", function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  // Our file var now holds the selected file
  file = files[0];
});

// This function is called when the user clicks on Upload to Parse. It will create the REST API request to upload this image to Parse.
$('#idofbutton').click(function() {
  var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/classname' + file.name;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'yourappkey');
      request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'yourrestapikey');
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
    },
    url: serverUrl,
    data: file,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {

        //Change variable to reflect your class to upload to
        var classUrl = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/classname";

        if(data) {

            var fileName = "" + data.name;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'yourappkey');
                    request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'yourrestapikey');
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
                },
                url: classUrl,
                data: '{"name" : "An Image", "image" : {"name" : '+"\""+fileName+"\""+', "__type" : "File"}}',
                processData: false,

                success: function(data) {
                    alert("data successfully uploaded.");
                },

                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.message);
                }
            });

        } else {
            //Data is null
            console.log("Data IS NULL");
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      alert(obj.error);
    }
  });
});
```